# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server (Virtual Machine)

Tags: sql, sql-server, iis, virtual-machine

First time stackoverflow poster,

I have 3 Virtual Machines, all running Windows Server 2012 Standard with IIS 8.0. They are connected through a Tier3.local domain. The VM’s are set up as a Webserver containing the applications, an Appserver containing the data services, and a Dataserver containing the SQL data base. I am trying to get the connection string between the Appserver and Dataserver to connect properly. I keep getting the error attached below, and have tried many solutions including ones found on this website, as well as the ones linked below

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-serverinstance-specified/

I am not sure if this problem is because of the VM's or because of a problem with the SQL server. My connection strings are as followed

Error Text:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Connection strings:

```
< add name="AutoTestServicesConnection" connectionString="Data Source=172.28.13.215/SQL2012;Database=AutoTest_MA_DEV_v9_4;UID=DBUSER;PWD=123456‌​;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=60;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 

< add name="AutoTestCentralDBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=172.28.13.215/SQL2012;Database=AutoTest_MA;UID=DBUSER;PWD=123456;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=60;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details/code/etc. because it is better readable there than in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Check these steps:

1. Make sure your server name is correct, e.g., no typo on the name.
2. Make sure your instance name is correct and there is actually such
   an instance on your target machine. [Update: Some application
   converts \ to . If you are not sure about your application, please
   try both ServerInstance and Server\Instance in your connection
   string]
3. Make sure the server machine is reachable, e.g, DNS can be resolve
   correctly, you are able to ping the server (not always true).
4. Make sure SQL Browser service and SQL Server(XX) services are running on the server.
5. If firewall is enabled on the server, you need to put sqlbrowser.exe
   and/or UDP port 1434 into exception.

Comment: 1. Checked the server name

2. Checked Instance Name and tried different ways including . and /

3. Pinged the server without issue

4. Both services are running on the Dataserver

5. Firewalls are turned off, and I have also added inbound rules for sqlbrowser.exe and port 1434.

Comment: @CjFerreira Do you get the Error number 26?

Comment: @CjFerreira Would you please send the screenshot?

Comment: Correction it does state Error 26, its the same error as attached above.